# Check values if none is found return message

Tags: powershell

I have this code that returns values less than -5 from an array using custom objects

`$Results.Where({$_.Value -lt -5d})`

that returns values I need but I am unable to write a condition that if nothing is returned from above code to write a message.

"Values within range"

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```bsh
if(($Results.Where({$_.Value -lt -5d})) -eq 0)
{
    Write-host ('Values within range.')
}
```

Comment: `if(!($Results.Where({$_.Value -lt -5d}))) {Write-host 'Values within range.'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `where` method, you will return a collection. Collections have a built-in property called `Count` that can be used to list the number of objects the collection contains.

```
if ($Results.Where({$_.Value -lt -5d}).Count -eq 0) {
# No objects are found
}
```

There are some potential caveats to this method. If your objects contain a property called `Count`, the collection specific `Count` property will override it when accessing `.Count` on the collection. If `$Results` is a single `PSCustomObject`, `$Results.Where()` will fail. You will need to turn `$Results` into a collection first: `@($Results).Where()`.

---

In PowerShell 7, you can use the ternary operator for `if-else` scenarios.

```
$Results.Where({$_.Value -lt -5d}) ? "Objects Found" : "Objects not found"
```